# HTML/CSS Dropdown Menu Display won't function

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, hover, hide

I am having difficulties with my dropdown menu. I cannot get the links to hide and the one time I did, I couldn't hover over them and I had way too many classes. Please help. I think my code is right but I don't see the problem.
HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
  <link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <title>Aquariust Blog</title>
</head>
  <body>
    <div class="container"></div>
    <ul class="nav">
       <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
      <li class="gallery"><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="goldphotos.html">Goldfish</a></li>
              <li><a href="freshphotos.html">Freshwater</a></li>
              <li><a href="saltphotos.html">Saltwater</a></li>
              <li><a href="videos.html">Videos</a></li>
      </ul>
        <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="forum.html">Forum</a><li>
        <li><a href="login.html">Login</a></li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>

CSS:
.nav{
 text-align:center; 
  list-style:none;
  background-color: #000000;
  opacity:0.6;
   height: 100px;
}
      .gallery ul li{
  display:none;
}
      .nav li:hover .gallery ul{
       display:block 
      }

body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;

}
.container{
 background:url("pics/tropicalfishtank.jpg");
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:700px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  overflow:auto;
}

.nav li{
        display:inline;
        margin: 2em;

}

.nav a{
 display:inline-block;
        text-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #ffffff;
        font-size: 3em;
        margin-top:25px;

}
.nav a:hover{
 color:blue; 
}
    div.twitterwidget
    {
position:absolute;
right:100px;
top:700px;
}

p.blogposts
{
 position:absolute;
  left:100px;
  top:120px;
  width:40%;
    margin:0 auto;
  font-size:26px;
  font-family:"Courier New",Georgia,Serif;
}
form.login{
 position:absolute;
  top:200px;
  left:100px;

}
```

Note:This stylesheet is used for all of my pages in case you're confused.

Comment: Your HTML is wrong. The drop down (`ul`) should be inside a `li` not outside of it. That is invalid html.

Comment: It's not *invalid*, but it isn't what you want. Put the inner `ul` inside of a `li` like drip suggests